# Remove white border around object tag

Tags: html, css

I'm currently looking for a way to remove a thin white border around the object tag... heres the code and what I have tried

```css
 .hr-ob {
        background-color: #003262;
        width: 50px;
        height: 10px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        border-width: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <div style="background-color: #000000;">
        <object border="0" class="hr-ob" data="" type="image/jpg"></object>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried border-width:0 in the CSS?

Comment: I don't think you can control that.  Try changing the `type` to `text/html`.  You'll notice the border disappears. I appears to be how the browser renders `image/jpeg` object types. I cannot find any reference on MDN or other sites about that particular border, only that the border attribute has been depreciated for object elements.

Comment: You were correct Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Johnathan's solution was still flawed as I was still getting a border, nevertheless wanted to share the solution I am using now:

```
<iframe class="hr-ob" width="50" height="5" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>

.hr-ob {
    background-color: #003262;
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you have mentioned the type as image/png and the data field is empty there seems to be a default internal-root-color that is appearing.

but when you place an image there is no border.

The border attribute of `<object>` is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

CSS syntax: `<object style="border:0px">`

```css
.hr-ob {
        background-color: #003262;
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
    }
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #000000;">
        <object style="border:0px;" class="hr-ob" data="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/4550ed/fff" type="image/jpg"></object>
    </div>
    
    
<div style="background-color: #000000;">
        <object style="border:0px;" class="hr-ob" data="" type="image/jpg"></object>
    </div>
```

Comment: As Johnathan mentioned, it was the use of the wrong type, once changed to text/html the need for border: 0 is no longer needed

Comment: @CameronGilbert okie and dont use border="0" attribute html5 doesnt support it